# Rule for connections number?

Tags: azure, wasabi

I have a WCF service that receives requests from a Sivlerlight client, it reads or writes to a SQL database and then it sends the response back to the client.

With 6 or 7 clients delay starts to increase and I would like to check if the more instances I have, the lesser delay (because of load balancing).

I am trying to implement the autoscaling application block but the rules for storage (such as queue lenght) or CPU usage aren't useful for me because I don't use a storage account and although I have 10 clients connected to the service, the instance CPU usage barely reaches 10%.

How could I set a rule to start a new instance when a certain number of connections is reached?

Comment: Are you asking about SQL connections or what kind of connections?

Comment: Client connections to the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture IIS's Requests Current performance counter and send it to [Windows Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411551.aspx).

I'm fairly certain that WASABi can scale your WCF/WebRole application based on any performance counter.  If for some reason WASABi cannot auto-scale you based on that performance counter or you need more features later, you can try [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) (personal plug)

But either way, ASP.NET\Requests Current (if you're using IIS to hose your WCF) seems like the performance counter you need.

Comment: I am using a cloud service from Azure to host my web role.